# Mutating columns of months and years together into a column of quarter and year in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
df = {'Month': [1, 8], 'Year': [2015, 2020]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df)
df
```

Would like to mutate it as a new column.

Desired output:

```
df = {'Month': [1, 8], 'Year': [2015, 2020], 'Quarter': ['Q12015', 'Q32020']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df)
df
```

Also would be grateful for comments **what is the best way to treat this data for modelling** with `scikit-learn`. For now I am thinking about strings and categorical variables without dummy variables, but appreciate any tips here. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the basic idea is to convert to datetime and the convert `to_period` with `Q` as Quarter (*you can still optimize this I think*)

```
df['Quarter'] = (pd.to_datetime(df[['Month','Year']].astype(str)
                   .agg('-'.join,1).radd("01-"),dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q'))
```

Or a simpler and better way as @Ben.T commented:

```
df['Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Month','Year']].assign(day=1)).dt.to_period('Q')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Month  Year Quarter
0      1  2015  2015Q1
1      8  2020  2020Q3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Quarter'] = df[['Year', 'Month']].astype(str).apply('-'.join,1)
df['Quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Quarter']), freq ='Q')
```