# Converting period[Q-DEC] column into a dataframe to a string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, period

I am trying to convert `period[Q-DEC]` column into a string for modelling.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307745/mutating-columns-of-months-and-years-together-into-a-column-of-quarter-and-year) helped me to do this.

My current data:

```
df = {'Month': [1, 8], 'Year': [2015, 2020]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df)
df['Quarter'] = (pd.to_datetime(df[['Month','Year']].astype(str)
               .agg('-'.join,1).radd("01-"),dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q'))

print(df)
df.dtypes
```

It gives me the output

```
   Month  Year Quarter
0      1  2015  2015Q1
1      8  2020  2020Q3
Month              int64
Year               int64
Quarter    period[Q-DEC]
dtype: object
```

Surprisingly I do not see many answer how to convert this `period` into string. I tried several solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800343/python-pandas-convert-type-from-pandas-period-to-string). Appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `.astype(str)`

```
df.Quarter=df.Quarter.astype(str)
df.dtypes

Month       int64
Year        int64
Quarter    object
dtype: object

print(df)
 Month    Year Quarter
0      1  2015  2015Q1
1      8  2020  2020Q3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try , also change the way you create the datetime

```
df['Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year*10+df.Month,format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('q').astype(str)
Out[19]: 
0    2015Q1
1    2020Q3
dtype: object
```